# How to calculate the duration between rows with the same stage value and then get the cumulative duration of each stage?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
dt_datetime        stage    proc_val
2011-11-13 11:00   0        20
2011-11-13 11:10   0        21
2011-11-13 11:30   1        25
2011-11-13 11:40   2        22
2011-11-13 11:55   2        28
2011-11-13 12:00   2        29
```

I need to add a new column called `stage_duration` and get the following result:

```
dt_datetime        stage    proc_val   stage_duration
2011-11-13 11:00   0        20         30
2011-11-13 11:10   0        21         30
2011-11-13 11:30   1        25         10
2011-11-13 11:40   2        22         20
2011-11-13 11:55   2        28         20
2011-11-13 12:00   2        29         20
```

How can I do it?

This is my current code snippet but it does not provide an expected result. It should calculate the duration between rows with the same stage value and then get the cumulative duration of each stage, but it doesn't.

```
df['stage_duration'] = df.groupby('stage')['dt_datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds() / 60
df['stage_duration'] = df['stage_duration'].cumsum()
```

**Update:**

The solution should also work if the dataframe contains multiple groups of stages, e.g. see stage 0 that starts at `2011-11-13 11:00` and `2011-11-13 12:00`. It has different durations in both cases.

```
dt_datetime        stage    proc_val   stage_duration
2011-11-13 11:00   0        20         30
2011-11-13 11:10   0        21         30
2011-11-13 11:30   1        25         10
2011-11-13 11:40   2        22         20
2011-11-13 11:55   2        28         20
2011-11-13 12:00   2        29         20
2011-11-13 12:00   0        20         70
2011-11-13 13:10   0        21         70
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last duration be 70?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option:

```
# ensure datetime
df['dt_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_datetime'])

# get min per group
s = df.groupby('stage')['dt_datetime'].min()

# add last date
s['last'] = df['dt_datetime'].max()

# compute delta and map
df['stage_duration'] = df['stage'].map(s.diff().shift(-1)
                                        .dt.total_seconds().div(60))
```

Output:

```
          dt_datetime  stage  proc_val  stage_duration
0 2011-11-13 11:00:00      0        20            30.0
1 2011-11-13 11:10:00      0        21            30.0
2 2011-11-13 11:30:00      1        25            10.0
3 2011-11-13 11:40:00      2        22            20.0
4 2011-11-13 11:55:00      2        28            20.0
5 2011-11-13 12:00:00      2        29            20.0
```

##### successive groups

```
# ensure datetime
df['dt_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt_datetime'])

# group by successive values
group = df['stage'].ne(df['stage'].shift()).cumsum()

# get min per group
s = df.groupby(group)['dt_datetime'].min()
s['last'] = df['dt_datetime'].max()

# compute delta and map
df['stage_duration'] = group.map(s.diff().shift(-1).dt.total_seconds().div(60))
```

Output:

```
          dt_datetime  stage  proc_val  stage_duration
0 2011-11-13 11:00:00      0        20            30.0
1 2011-11-13 11:10:00      0        21            30.0
2 2011-11-13 11:30:00      1        25            10.0
3 2011-11-13 11:40:00      2        22            20.0
4 2011-11-13 11:55:00      2        28            20.0
5 2011-11-13 12:00:00      2        29            20.0
6 2011-11-13 12:00:00      0        20            70.0
7 2011-11-13 13:10:00      0        21            70.0
```

Comment: will it work if I have different potential durations of stage 0?

Comment: Please see my update regarding my question. I think that your code looks for the max time difference per stage, right? For example, in my update it would assign the value 60 to stage 0 in all places, is it correct?

Comment: @Fluxy it's calculating the difference between the earliest date of a stage and the next one, except for the last group for which it is the difference between the last date and earliest of this group. I added an alternative if you want to group by successive identical stages